# How to get a user's input into a class's member variable and dereference it

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```cpp
class cookie{
public:
    cookie() = default;
    int*p_member{};
    int case{};
private:
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cookie cold;
    cout << "Type what you want into the cookie p_member variable " << endl;
    std::cin >> cold.*p_member; // this doesn't work 
}
```

I wanna know how to get access to the classes pointer variable put data inside it and then derefrence it.

Comment: why is the member a pointer? You need an `int` to store an integer. A pointer is not sufficient, your pointer points nowhere

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number how come, it doesn't point anywhere ?

Comment: you do not make it point anywhere. The pointer is not initialized to point to a `double`

Comment: Is this about a member that is a pointer or a pointer-to-member?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The pointer is a nullptr because i want to put something inside it , int the main function.

Comment: a pointer to a `int` stores an adress of an `int`, it does not store an `int`. There is no `int` in your code to which you could assign

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz it's about a member that is a pointer.I would like to assign a value to the member, and then dereference the member so i could print it out.

Comment: "I would like to assign a value to the member" you can assign to it the address of an `int`, but you need an `int` first

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number so i can't assign it directly like a normal pointer.

Comment: You need to first assing the address to the pointer, and that address has to be of a memory location that's accessible to you. In this case the easiest way would be to create an `int` variable and get its address via the address-of operator. After you have obtained the address, you can initialize the data in that memory region and subsequently read from it via your dereferenced pointer.

Comment: @EkeneNwokedi `case` cannot be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, make sure that you're not dereferencing a null or uninitialized pointer. Otherwise you'll have undefined behavior.

---

> it's about a member that is a pointer.I would like to assign a value to the member, and then dereference the member so i could print it out.

You can use a *pointer to member syntax* for this task as shown below:

```
class cookie{
public:
    
    int var;
    int cookie::*p_member=&cookie::var; //p_member can point to an int data member of an cookie object 
    
};

int main(){
    cookie cold{};
    
    cout << "Type what you want into the cookie p_member variable " << endl;
    std::cin >> cold.*cold.p_member;  //take input from user directly into var using member pointer syntax
    
    std::cout << "var: " << cold.var << std::endl; //print var to confirm that it is correctly set
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/E_Bid2RXx)